# C# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture says en_US but my Windows settings are set to South Africa

Tags: c#, internationalization, .net-4.5, windows-8.1, cultureinfo

I changed my Region/Location in my Windows 8.1 control panel to be South Africa. When I start up my app from Visual Studio 2013 and get the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture it still says "en-US".

```
public CultureInfo getCurrentCulture() {
    if (CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture != null) {
        return CultureInfo.DefaulThreadCurrentUICulture;
    } else {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    }
}
```

I've also tried CultureInfo.CurrentCulture instead of CurrentUICulture, but they are behaving the same way. How do I determine what the user's real locale is via code? Or am I setting the region incorrectly via the Windows settings?

My app formats currency strings and such and I need to make sure it is using the correct currency symbols. South Africa is a good use case for me because they still use the English language, but just have different regional number formatting.

Comment: Have you also changed the system locale (region -> administrative tab -> language for non-unicode programs)?

Comment: @MarcelN. I set that to "English (South Africa)" as well and the culture info still says "en-US"

Comment: Are you changing the "Format:" drop-down under the "Formats" tab of "Region and Language", or the "Current Location:" drop-down under the "Location" tab, or both?  Warning: I'm using Win7 so the question may be inapplicable.

Comment: @dbc Oh, it does look like there is also a Format tab. I set that to "English (South Africa)" and restarted my app but the CultureInfo is still "en-US". :/ I'm wondering if I want my users to have to go through all of this, or if I should just offer them an in-app Region selector.

Comment: I experimented a bit with VS2008, it looks like 1) `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is defined by the "Formats" tab, and 2) changing the format isn't always picked up when I rerun my application from inside Visual Studio -- maybe because the [Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx) holds on to obsolete information?  Closing and re-opening the solution fixes that.  Explicitly killing the hosting process from the Task Manager probably would also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I should make this an answer.

Windows distinguishes between the physical location of the user, the desired localization (formatting) properties, and the running language.  For instance, a Spanish-speaking user could be located in the UK but want American English formatting.  [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) refers to the settings under the ["Formats"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2008/02/05/yacvcp-yet-another-currentculture-vs-currentuiculture-post.aspx) tab of the [Regions](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8) control panel.  (The user interfaces shown in one of the links above are a little out-of-date for Win8; see [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/32820-date-time-format-change-windows-8-a.html) for the Win8 analogs.)

This article has a little more information about the various culture properties and how they are set in the user interface: [YACVCP (Yet another CurrentCulture vs. CurrentUICulture post)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2008/02/05/yacvcp-yet-another-currentculture-vs-currentuiculture-post.aspx)

So, to test South African currency strings and such, you have to change the "Format" drop-down to "English (South Africa)" and rerun.

Also, by experimentation, I have found that Visual Studio 2008 (what I am using) doesn't always pick up the change in locale when I rerun my application.  This may be some sort of bug with the [Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx).  Restarting and rerunning my application usually seems to cure the problem.  Closing and re-opening Visual Studio always does.

(Note -- I'm using Win7.)